# Trouble loading JSON data into a ExtJS datastore

Tags: json, extjs, extjs4

I've tried every combination I can think of in terms of how to configure my ExtJS datastore to read my incoming JSON data.  I'm getting this JSON data in:

```
[{ "data_type": {"attribute1" : "value1",
                  "attribute2" : "value2",
                  "attribute3" : "value3" 
                  }
 },
 { "data_type": {"attribute1": "value4",
                  "attribute2" : "value5",
                  "attribute3" : "value6" 
                  }
 }
]
```

I don't want to parse the JSON and reformat it in order to make ExtJS happy because it seems redundant.  What I want to end up with is a datastore which would allow me to do:

```
    Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', 
    {
        id: 'junk',
        renderTo: 'slider',
        width: 960,
        height:600,
        layout: 'vbox',
        items: [
           {
              xtype: 'grid',
              title: 'foobar',
              height: 400,
              width: 700,
              store: my_store,
              viewConfig: { emptyText: 'No data' },
              columns: [
                  {
                     text: 'column1',
                     dataIndex: 'attribute1'
                  },{
                     text: 'column2',
                     dataIndex: 'attribute2'
                  },{
                     text: 'column3',
                     dataIndex: 'attribute3'
                  }
              ]
           }
        ]
    }
```

I know ExtJS knows how to parse this JSON, because I can do:

```
var foo = Ext.decode(data);
var good_data = foo[0].data_type.attribute1
```

And that returns 'value1' as I would expect.  Can anyone help me understand the magical incantation to get a datamodel and store to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I have the data in a javascript variable.  Currently it's document.jsonData, which I know is not great but I was going to fix that later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should create model:

```
Ext.define('SomeModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'attribute1'},
        {name: 'attribute2'},
        {name: 'attribute3'}
    ]
});
```

Then you can configure store to support your data format by setting `record` property to `data_type`:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad: true,
    data : data,
    model: 'SomeModel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            record: 'data_type'
        }
    }
});
```

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/lolo/WfXK6/1/

Comment: Thanks!  The link to jsfiddle is really helpful, and I seem to have found out that all is not what it seems with my incoming json, because with static data in the same format it works, but with the incoming data it's not working.. looks like some hidden characters or something like that confusing ExtJS.

Comment: Turns out what I needed to do was do: `var my_data = JSON.parse(jsonString)`  and then hand the my_data variable to the data store rather than handing it plain text.