# Reading a Json object as "store" for a grid in a new window with Extjs

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs4

My question is pretty like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003385/trouble-loading-json-data-into-a-extjs-datastore) but it has a problem more than this, as the JSON has to be loaded in a new window. Something like [this](http://www.objis.com/formationextjs/lib/extjs-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.window.Window.html). As you can see the store has a place inside the ITEMS of the new window.

That's it, I am not able to sum the two solutions, one to read the JSON and one to make a grid in a new window, to make a grid which could read the json I've passed to the new window. How do I have to design the store line in the second example (or in my example below) to make it read a variable which contains all my JSON data and which is already recorded and ready to be used?

```
var obj = response;
try {
  obj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
} catch (error) {}
if (obj) {
  Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    title: 'Hello',
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: {
      xtype: 'grid',
      border: false,
      columns: [{
        text: 'id',
        flex: 1,
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'id'
      }, {
        text: 'name',
        width: 300,
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'name'
      }],
      store: Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {}) //this is the line I have to change
    }
  }).show();
} else {
  alert("Invalid response")
}
```

Comment: The error i get changing the "store" line like in the example i mentioned of json is: `TypeError: d.model is undefined`. Agnese

Answer (score 0):

Working, but still not loading the json data fully cause the data are without a root. This is the answer i found for the moment.

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
          title: 'Admants',
          height: 200,
          width: 400,
          layout: 'fit',
          items: {  
              xtype: 'grid',
              border: false,
              columns: [
                      {text     : 'id',
        flex     : 1,
        sortable : true,
        dataIndex: 'id'
        },
        {
                    text     : 'name',
                    width    : 300,
                    sortable : true,
                    dataIndex: 'name'
                    }],
            store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            storeId: 'My Grid',
            fields: ['id', 'name'],
            data: obj,
            proxy: {
                type: 'memory',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
        record: ""
                }
            }
        })
        }}).show();
```

This is partially solved.